# TCP/IP Client and Server basic using and references

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, client-server, nuget-package

I have installed `TCP/IP`  from `VS15 NuGet Packeges` into my project and in References it is as `SimpleTCP`, I've rebuild project, but for  `SimpleTcpClient client;` it says:

> Suppression State Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name
>   'SimpleTcpServer' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

not sure what can be cause of that, maybe I missed some references or even using.

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SimpleTcpClient client;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client.WriteLineAndGetReplay(txtMessage.Text, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            client = new SimpleTcpClient();
            client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.DataRecevived += Client_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                textBox1.Text += e.MessageString;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Server
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SimpleTcpServer server;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = new SimpleTcpServer();
            server.Delimeter = 0x13;
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;
        }

        private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            txtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                e.ReplyLine(string.Format("You said: {0}", e.MessageString));
            });          
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtStatus.Text += "Server starting...";
            System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(txtHost.Text));
            server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (server.IsStarted)
            {
                server.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine on my side. Would you mind updating the question to include full code?

Comment: There's already a perfectly good `TcpListener` in .NET. No Nuget required. Just sayin'

Comment: @Reousa Asteron  Hello, I've added full code above

Comment: @MickyD Hello, not sure what is wrong there, I've added updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you get this error because you have not included `using SimpleTCP;` in your code.

The start of each of your forms should look something like this:

```
using SimpleTCP;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

With that said, the code would still have some problems.

1. You do not have `client.Connect(IP, PORT);` in your client form. In order to create a `server < > client` connection, there must be a listening server and a client to connect to it. In your case, there is only a listening server.
2. In your `server` form, you should be calling `IPAddress.Parse()` instead. Usage example: `IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");`
3. You do not need to `Invoke` any of your `Form` members as you are not using any sort of multi-threading, unless `SimpleTCP` does so by default, which is very unlikely.

Furthermore, the whole project seems to be a mess. If you're still starting out, I would highly recommend using `Console Application` as they're more forgiving and rather simple to use.

I would also recommend learning more about [C# events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) and how they work.

Here is a `server < > client` project using `SimpleTCP`, your configurations and `Console Application` to get you started.

Server:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using SimpleTCP;
using System.Text;

namespace server
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleTcpServer server = new SimpleTcpServer(); //Instantiate server.
            server.Delimiter = 0x13; //Config
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8; //Config
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived; //Subscribe to DataRecieved event.
            IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //IP Address using .Parse()
            int port = 6500; //Port number
            server.Start(ip, port); //Start listening to incoming connections and data.
            Console.ReadKey(); //Pause the console.
        }

        static void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.MessageString); //Write message to console.
            string replyMessage = String.Format("You said {0}", m.MessageString); //This is the reply message
            m.ReplyLine(replyMessage); //Send reply message back to client.
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using SimpleTCP;
using System.Text;

namespace client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleTcpClient client = new SimpleTcpClient(); //Instantiate the client
            client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8; //Config
            client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived; //Subscribe to the DataRecieved event.
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 6500); //Connect to the server
            while(true) //Keep the console open until you close it.
            {
                //As long as the console is open, every message you type will be sent to the server.
                client.WriteLineAndGetReply(Console.ReadLine(), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); 
            }
        }
        static void Client_DataReceived(object sender, Message m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.MessageString); //Write recieved reply from server to console.
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you on your journey, goodluck!

Comment: Let me know if I've missed anything!

Comment: Hello, your code works well, and it is answer to my question, but seems like,  it would be good for this answer, to avoid   'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException', in case if server is off and client tryies to connect, it throws me exception

Comment: @nikorio There is something called `exception handling` for such cases. I have tried to keep the code as simple as possible, but you could expand it as you see fit.
Kindly refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx for `exception handling`. There is a lot to learn, just keep reading! Goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old, but I guess this could interesting.
I came here because I watched a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve2LX1tOwIM) with exactly exactly the code above.
The problem in the video is that I guess is cutted and it is not possible to see a part of the code. In the client code of the video, as in the code above in the question, some lines are not shown completely. It seems it's missing the line client.Connect(TxtHost.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TxtPort.Text));
There is an error in that video even in the server event btnStart_Click in which is shown first the code System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(txtHost.Text)); as in the server code above. I got error in debug even for this, watching the video near the end it is possible that the code changed (but it's not shown in all video when...) in this System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(TxtHost.Text);

For who came exactly from that video I post the complete code, with those corrections, and a bit of other changes:

client:

```
using SimpleTCP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace TelnetClient
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            SimpleTcpClient client;

            private void BtnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    //System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(TxtHost.Text);
                    client.Connect(TxtHost.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TxtPort.Text));

                    BtnConnect.Enabled = false;
                    BtnClose.Enabled = true;
                    BtnSend.Enabled = true;
                    TxtHost.Enabled = false;
                    TxtPort.Enabled = false;
                    TxtMessages.Enabled = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    TxtStatus.Text = "Error during connection... please check host and port...";
                    TxtStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }

            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                client = new SimpleTcpClient();
                client.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
                client.DataReceived += Client_DataReceived;
            }

            private void Client_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
            {
                TxtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {
                    TxtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                    TxtStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                });
            }

            private void BtnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                //client.WriteLineAndGetReply(TxtMessages.Text, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                client.WriteLineAndGetReply(TxtMessages.Text, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));

                TxtMessages.Text = "";
            }

            private void BtnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {

                    client.Disconnect();

                    BtnConnect.Enabled = true;
                    BtnClose.Enabled = false;
                    BtnSend.Enabled = false;
                    TxtHost.Enabled = true;
                    TxtPort.Enabled = true;
                    TxtMessages.Enabled = false;
                    TxtMessages.Text = "";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    TxtStatus.Text = "Error during closing connection...";
                    TxtStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

server:

```
using SimpleTCP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TelnetServer
{

    public partial class TelnetServer : Form
    {
        public TelnetServer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SimpleTcpServer server;

        private void TelnetServer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            server = new SimpleTcpServer();
            server.Delimiter = 0x13;//enter
            server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
            server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;

        }

        private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            TxtStatus.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
            {
                TxtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;
                TxtStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
                //e.ReplyLine(String.Format("You said: {0}", e.MessageString));
                server.Broadcast(e.MessageString);
            });
        }

        private void BtnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Net.IPAddress ip = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(TxtHost.Text);
                //System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(TxtHost.Text));
                server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(TxtPort.Text));

                TxtStatus.Text = "Server starting...";
                TxtStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);

                BtnStart.Enabled = false;
                BtnStop.Enabled = true;
                TxtHost.Enabled = false;
                TxtPort.Enabled = false;

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TxtStatus.Text = "Error during starting... please check host and port...";
                TxtStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }   

        }

        private void BtnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnStart.Enabled = true;
            BtnStop.Enabled = false;
            TxtHost.Enabled = true;
            TxtPort.Enabled = true;

            if (server.IsStarted)
                server.Stop();

            TxtStatus.Text = "Server stopped... ";
            TxtStatus.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```